# center content in panels

Tags: panels

I am new to panels, and am attempting to design a panel page. Is there any simple way to center content in panels? I can mess around in css, but I feel like I must be missing some simple solution.

How do you center content in panels 3?

Comment: It's css. For example,  .pane-views-abc .pane-content {text-align: center;} There are some modules if you Google it or you could create your own style but css is probably the easiest.

Comment: WOW ironically I just discovered a CSS bug in SE :O

Comment: Thank you. I was hopeful that the answer was easier, but CSS isn't so bad. What would you suggest I modify with the css? The pane, the image, the region, or something else entirely?

Comment: Is it D7 or D8?